# Hibernate: filter by list using criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a Doctor entity. Each doctor has a list of HealthInsurance which is another entity.

My goal is to make a search system based on the HealthInsurance's the user select. I have to get all doctors that has at least 1 HealthInsurance contained in the user health insurance's list. Something like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Doctor.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("healthInsurances", userHealthInsurances));
return criteria.list();
```

But this code is throwing the following exception: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.

Is there any way of doing this using Criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Doctor.class);
criteria.createCriteria("healthInsurances").add(Restrictions.in("id", userSelectedIds));
return criteria.list();
```

You may get the same functionality through `createAlias`. Have a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) for more examples.

Comment: It worked, thanks.
As I reveice a list of entities instead of a list of ids, is there any way to perform the same operation without having to generate the list of ids?

Comment: It might work if you overwrite the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of your `HealthInsurance` object with its id and pass `userHealthInsurances` list as the parameter of `in` method; but not sure about this ;)

Comment: You mean like I propose in the question? When I do this I get the error I said (java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1). And if keep what you said but changing "userSelectedIds" to "userHealthInsurances" I get the following error: java.lang.ClassCastException: HealthInsurance cannot be cast to Long.

Comment: I meant the second one(that you got ClassCastException) and turns out that it doesn't work.